# Can I score each section in a google form based on multiple choice questions

Tags: google-forms

I have a google form I am using to try to develop a scoring criteria for a disease. It has multiple sections (Heart, Kidney, Lung etc). Each section has multiple questions about how active their disease is. I want to give an overall score of A to E in each section (Heart - A etc) based on the results of the questions.

For example if a person answers "1" to any question in a subheading they score an "A", failing that if they answer 2 to any question they score a "B" and so forth.

Is this possible to code into Google Forms? I have tried using Formfascade but would prefer a native solution

Tried using Formfascade and Scorecery but I don't see, to be able to make an alphanumeric score, only sum up a numeric one